# Can I use one instead of my two view models?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel

Can I use one ViewModel instead of my two view models(AboutViewModel and AboutListItemViewModel)?

Here is my code:

```
class AboutAdapter(private val clickListener: OnItemClickListener?) : AbstractListAdapter() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AboutItemViewHolder {
        val binding: AboutBinding = DataBindingUtil
            .inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), R.layout.view_item_about,
                parent, false
            )
        return AboutItemViewHolder(binding = binding)
    }

    override fun onBindHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int, item: Any) {
        (holder as AboutItemViewHolder).bind(item as SettingsItemViewModel, listener = clickListener)
    }
}
```

My AboutFragment:

```
class AboutFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: AboutViewModel
    private lateinit var viewModelFactory: AboutViewModelFactory
    private var onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener = object : OnItemClickListener {
        override fun onItemClick(titleName: Int) {
            when (titleName) {
                R.string.about_terms_service -> {
                    activity?.addFragment(WebViewFragment.newInstance(TERMS_LINK, getString(R.string.about_terms_service)))
                }
                R.string.about_open_source_licenses -> activity?.addFragment(LicensesFragment())
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        viewModelFactory = AboutViewModelFactory(requireContext(), onItemClickListener)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
            .get(AboutViewModel::class.java)

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base_list, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        activityComponents?.updateAppbarTitleWithFabAction(getString(R.string.about_feature_title))
        setupViews()
    }

    private fun setupViews() {
        try {
            val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            recyclerView?.layoutManager = layoutManager
            val dividerItemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(context, layoutManager.orientation)
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(context ?: return, R.drawable.shape_full_divider)?.let {
                dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(it)
            }
            recyclerView?.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration)
            recyclerView?.adapter = AboutAdapter(viewModel.onItemClickListener).apply {
                data = viewModel.getListItems()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.log()
        }
    }
}
```

My AboutItemViewHolder:

```
class AboutItemViewHolder(
    binding: AboutBinding
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

    private var aboutBinding: AboutBinding? = null

    init {
        this.aboutBinding = binding
    }

    fun bind(item: SettingsItemViewModel, listener: OnItemClickListener?) {
        aboutBinding?.about = AboutListItemViewModel(item)
        aboutBinding?.onItemClickListener = listener
        aboutBinding?.executePendingBindings()
    }
}

interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(titleName: Int)
}
```

My first ViewModel which I used in adapter AboutListItemViewModel:

```
class AboutListItemViewModel(item: SettingsItemViewModel) {

    val titleName: Int = item.titleId
    val subTitleName: String? = item.value
    var isVisible: Boolean = item.value != null
}
```

My second ViewModel which I used in fragment AboutViewModel:

```
class AboutViewModel(val appContext: Context, val onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener): ViewModel() {

    fun getListItems(): List<SettingsItemViewModel> {
        return listOf(
            SettingsItemViewModel(
                titleId = R.string.about_app_version,
                value = AppTools.getAppVersionName(appContext)
            ),
            SettingsItemViewModel(
                titleId = R.string.about_copyright,
                value = appContext.getString(R.string.about_copyright_description)
            ),
            SettingsItemViewModel(
                titleId = R.string.about_terms_service,
                itemIsClickable = true
            ),
            SettingsItemViewModel(
                titleId = R.string.about_open_source_licenses,
                itemIsClickable = true
            )
        )
    }
}
```

My AboutViewModelFactory:

```
class AboutViewModelFactory(val appContext: Context, private val onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(AboutViewModel::class.java)) {
            return AboutViewModel(appContext, onItemClickListener) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

SettingsViewModel is simple data class:

```
data class SettingsItemViewModel(
    @StringRes val titleId: Int,
    val value: String? = null,
    val switchEnabled: Boolean? = null,
    val isChecked: Boolean = false,
    val itemIsClickable: Boolean = false,
    val colorResId: Int = R.color.black
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ViewModel`s are for the MVVM pattern, in which a `ViewModel` is ignorant of any View type classes, such as an `OnItemClickListener`, so you have an unintended usage where you are passing listeners to `ViewModel` factories. This also will leak your Fragment or Activity if there is a configuration change.

I don't see you even using the listener from within the `ViewModel`, so you could completely eliminate this property and the factory altogether. You can inherit from `AndroidViewModel` and take a single `Context` argument in your constructor. Then you can use `by viewModels()` for your `ViewModel` property.

Without these view callback arguments, there would be nothing to limit you from putting all of this in a single `ViewModel` implementation.

It's also odd that your view model has a function that returns a list of other ViewModels. Why can these just be simple data classes? A ViewModel is shouldn't be directly instantiated yourself (except by a factory implementation). Otherwise, its lifecycle won't be managed.

Comment: SettingsItemViewModel is simple `data class`, i updated question.
So if i undestood you correctly i need to remove clicklistener from my factory?

Comment: Now i updated code like this
https://gist.github.com/mnewlive/41da1828713e9a37e5d36036ccb607da
Can u check please?